# Sprite Looking At Cursor For A Shooting Game Using LÖVE2D

Tags: lua, cursor, game-physics, love2d

In lua and LÖVE2D , I wanted to try to make a simple game about shooting enemies,
in which player stands still but looks (points) at the cursor so it can shoot the enemy when you point at it with cursor.
This is my code. It doesn't work.

```
local data = {}
push = require 'push'
Class = require 'class'
WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720

VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 432
VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 243


function love.load()
    MCSprite = love.graphics.newImage("MC.png")
    data.width = MCSprite:getWidth()
    data.height = MCSprite:getHeight()
    data.x = love.graphics.getWidth() / 2 
    data.y = love.graphics.getHeight() / 2
    data.originX =data.width / 2
    data.originY =data.height / 2
    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter('nearest', 'nearest')
    love.window.setTitle('Alien Shooter')
    math.randomseed(os.time())
    smallFont = love.graphics.newFont('font.ttf', 8)
    largeFont = love.graphics.newFont('font.ttf', 16)
    scoreFont = love.graphics.newFont('font.ttf', 32)
    love.graphics.setFont(smallFont)
    PlayerScore=0

    push:setupScreen(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, {
        fullscreen = false,
        resizable = true,
        vsync = true
    })
    gameState = 'start'
end
function love.resize(w, h)
    push:resize(w, h)
end

function love.update(dt)
    if gameState=='start' then

        
        x2 = love.mouse.getX( )
        y2 = love.mouse.getY( )
        angle = math.deg(math.atan2(y2-data.originY,x2-data.originX)) 


    end
end


function love.keypressed(key)
    if key == 'escape' then
        love.event.quit()
    end
end

function love.draw()
    push:apply('start')
    love.graphics.printf('ALIEN SHOOTER!', 0, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2 - 6, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
    love.graphics.printf('Click SPACE to Start!', 0,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2 + 12, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, 'center')
    push:apply('end')             
    love.graphics.draw(MCSprite, data.x, data.y, data.originX, data.originY,angle)
end
```

I tried looking at internet but I am not good at it it seems. I tried changing code but I am new to it so it didn't work.

Comment: Why did you call `math.deg`? The angle should be in radians.

Comment: I tried changing it to math.rad but its still flying away. sprite is not seen.

Comment: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-math.atan2 Just remove it, the returned value is already in radians.